# Java: Get element before or after a given one in an Iterable

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Is there a non verbose way (for example using a method call from an existing library, be it guava or similar) to retrieve the previous and the following element from an Iterable, given one of its elements?

I would like to have a general solution that fits for Iterable (or Collection if it is cool enough), so please do not post solutions that work just for Set or List and so on (maybe add a comment :) ).

I need either one or the other, I do not want to find both previous and following element in one method.

My solution is below. If you feel like commenting on returning null instead of throwing IllegalArgumentException or similar, please feel free to do so. The getElementBefore() method creates a new list, which I am not that happy with too.

```
public static <C> C getElementAfter(final C element, final Iterable<C> iterable) {
    Iterator<C> iterator = iterable.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next().equals(element)) {
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                return iterator.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Iterable does not contain element.");
}

public static <C> C getElementBefore(final C element, final Iterable<C> iterable) {
    return getElementAfter(element, Lists.reverse(Lists.newArrayList(iterable)));
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you calling `getElementAfter()` from `getElementBefore()`? No need to replicate all that code.

Comment: @Keppil Yes, you are right, I fixed it, thanks. I do not like much the overhead of creating a new list, but I could not find anything better up to now.

Comment: Simpler way to retrieve the previous and the following element from an Iterable? Haven't seen one. Reason might be that an `Iterable` is kind of the wrong "collection" type. A `List` provides direct access based on index (`List.get(List.indexOf(element) + 1)`) and you would most likely use that instead of iterable.

Comment: @zapl I stepped into this problem while working with sets. You might need to use Set because it offers other features like uniqueness or sorting, which are not built-in with List. Guava's Iterables.get(iterable, position) makes a feature of lists available to all iterables, for example.

Comment: Oh nice. Your implementation is more efficient though since you don't need to iterate twice to find the element then find the one before / after. And if you happen to use a [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) you could probably use `higher` and `lower`.

Answer (score 1):

Returning null would probably make more sense in this case, as it may not be an exception.

Your getElementBefore implementation could be improved:

```
public static <C> C getElementBefore(final C element, final Iterable<C> iterable) {
    C previous = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        C current = iterator.next();
        if (current.equals(element)) {
            return previous;
        } else {
            previous = current;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Iterator<C> iterator = iterable.iterator();
C before = null;
C after = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    C current = iterator.next();
    if (current.equals(element)) {
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            after = iterator.next();
        }
        break;
    }
    before = current;
}
```

This should save the element before in `before` and the element after in `after`.